# C# Regular Expression. Uniqueness of the character

Tags: c#, regex

How can I check the uniqueness of the specified character in the line with regular expression. For example I have a line with different symbols. If there is only one dot(.) in the line then it must match with expression.
I tried to do like this

```
public static void GetLines(List<string> lines)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"^.*\..*");
        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            if (rx.IsMatch(item))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

This prints only lines where exists the dot(.) character. I think that this method will work if I write the expression like this `@"^.*\.{1}.*"`
But it doesn't work.

Comment: It must be regex? Because is much easier without it

Comment: I wrote the same with LINQ. But now I want to write it with regular expression.)))

Comment: Writing {1} in front of any character is redundant as that is by default with any character written in a regex. When you write this in your regex ^.*\..* then it will match any line that at least contains one dot character and will also match lines which contains multiple dot characters anywhere in the line

Comment: Writing {1} in front of any character is means that character must be exactly one time in the line, isn't it?

Comment: @Koryun, {1} **behind** a character, not in front of it. Otherwise, yes... But as the prior comment already stated, `{1}` is redundant and can and should thus be omitted (it would just be noise, making it harder to read a regex pattern). As an example, these three regex patterns would all be equivalent `H{1}e{1}l{2}o{1}`, `Hel{2}o`, `Hello`. Now, would you still prefer using {1}? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your regex and write it like this if you want it to match to input that only and only contains single dot character.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^[^.]*\.[^.]*$");
```

Explanation:

- [^.]* ensures it matches any character zero or more times but not dot
- . followed by a dot character
- [^.]* again ensures it matches any character zero or more times but not dot

Similarly you can do it for any character just like dot.